# How to use Django rest framework query parameters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an API with Django and I'm having a hard time understanding how query string parameters work: So far I created an endpoint which gives out a list of products and know I want to be able to filter those products by name like `/api/Products/name=guitar` or any equivalent of `/api/Products?name=guitar`

I created this view and serializer:

```
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = ProductJoinShop.objects.raw(f'select * from Product join Shop using (id_shop) limit 12')
        name = self.request.query_params.get('name')
        if name is not None:
            queryset = ProductJoinShop.objects.raw(f'select * from Product join Shop using (id_shop) where name like \'%{name}%\' limit 12')
        return queryset
```

And this is my urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()                   
router.register(r'Products', views.ProductView, 'Products')  
router.register(r'Products/(?P<name>.+)/$', views.ProductView, 'ProductsSearch')  

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls))
]
```

This doesn't crash but for /api/Products/guitar/ I get nothing back. I also tried /api/Products/?name=guitar/ and that throws an error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `router.register(r'Products/', views.ProductView, 'ProductsSearch')`

And then use your URL like `/api/Products/?name=guitar`

Another possible error `return queryset` should be indentation problem where you you need to place properly.

```
serializer_class = ProductSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = ProductJoinShop.objects.raw(f'select * from Product join Shop using (id_shop) limit 12')
    name = self.request.query_params.get('name')
    if name is not None:
       queryset = ProductJoinShop.objects.raw(f'select * from Product join Shop using (id_shop) where name like \'%{name}%\' limit 12')
       return queryset
```